# ImageView PNG is replaced by the default Android Icon on the Galaxy S5 Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a very simple activity showing an image:

```
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

   <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/my_image"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/activation_background" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`my_image.png` is only in `/res/drawable-xhdpi/` and it is working fine for all the phones I've tried so far, except the Galaxy S5 with Lollipop (it is working on 4.4). On this specific phone and version, the `ImageView` shows instead a kind of default Android icon that is even not in my project.

To fix it, I need to put `my_image.png` in `/res/drawable-xxhdpi/`. But I don't understand this behavior. It is working fine on the Nexus 6 without the need to do that. Is it a known issue of the 5.0 version of the S5? Is there another way to do it rather than moving the image to `drawable-xxhdpi`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the solution to my problem is a bit odd. I fixed it by simply renaming the drawable `activation_bg` to `something_activation_bg`. Please note that anything other than `activation_bg` was working, except `activation_background` which led to the same issue.

I don't know why this is an issue specifically on the Lollipop version of the Galaxy S5. There shouldn't be any conflicts with anything external to the app so it is really odd.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you should be creating drawables for each size screen.  Android Studio has a tool to do this for you - right click on drawable and select new -> image asset

Otherwise, in Lollipop and up I believe vector graphics are supported - check here:
https://developer.android.com/training/material/drawables.html

Comment: I know this is a best practice, but I don't want to do it to keep the app size lower until the image look bad on big devices (which is not the case so far). However, this is not the cause of the problem as it work for every other images or on every other phones... I don't understand this behavior

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to provide the image at the xxhdpi resolution you definitely should add it. It is best practice to have all your graphics defined in mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, and xxhdpi folders.

Otherwise a workaround would be to simply make a copy of the image in the xhdpi folder and add it to the xxhdpi folder. That way phones at xxhdpi will still have a drawable resource to load.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tried that but, even if it is working, it does not explain why this specific image is not working while all the other xhdpi drawables work perfectly fine. It does not explain either why it is working on other phones like Nexus 6, or Galaxy S5 pre-Lollipop